MakeFile no rule issue
I have two sub folders in my project. First one is the Source folder which contains main.cpp file
and the second one is ImGui folder which contains all needed ImGui cpp and header files.
ProjectFolder
  |
  |
Source
    main.cpp
  |
  |
ImGui
    all aimgui.cpp and header files

and I want to compile it.
this is my MakeFile
`
CC     = g++
OBJ    = main.o
CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++17 -MMD -MP -g -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/
CFLAGS += -IImGui/
CFLAGS += -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread
CFLAGS += -std=c++11
CFLAGS += -BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS
CFLAGS += `pkg-config --cflags glfw3`

LDLIBS = -L/usr/local/lib/ -pthread
LDLIBS += -lGL -ffast-math
LDLIBS += `pkg-config --static --libs glfw3`

SRC_DIR = Source
IMGUI_DIR = ImGui
OBJ_DIR = obj
BIN_DIR = bin

EXE = $(BIN_DIR)/Application

SRC = $(shell find $(SRC_DIR)/ -name '*.cpp')
GUI_SRC = $(shell find $(IMGUI_DIR)/ -name '*.cpp')

OBJS := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRC))
OBJS += $(patsubst $(IMGUI_DIR)%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(GUI_SRC))

.PHONY:
    install clean

install: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJS) | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o:$(SRC_DIR)%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o:$(IMGUI_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(BIN_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    @$(RM) -rv $(BIN_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR)

-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)

`
And I'm getting this error:
make: *** No rule to make target 'main.cpp', needed by 'bin/Application'.  Stop

I can't understand why it's not working. Do you have any example of MakeFile that compiles CPP files from multiple Source folders?
What's wrong with my makeup file? Or what I have to change to make it work?

It looks like you forgot TABs. Makefile does require that body of recipe started with a \t symbol. Your sample shows that body is started on the beginning of a line.

@WhiteOwl no I did not forgot, I just copied the whole makefile and this webpage shows like that. Let me edit it.

@WhiteOwl While true, missing tabs usually lead to other errors (missing separator, or something similar IIRC). Could be problem copy-pasting the makefile, or could be that the OP doesn't copy-paste the full and complete build output, so we don't have all the information.

@Someprogrammerdude I edited my post. This is the whole Makefile. What else do you need?

I can't understand why it's not working. -- Saying this means that you have had successful make files working before this one?  If so, have you compared what you're doing now to what was working before?  If this is your first make file ever, you should have started out with something simple (a "Hello World" version of a make file), get that working, and build up from a working baseline.

I also tried OBJS = $(addprefix ,$(patsubst $(SRC)/%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(notdir $(SRC)))) but the same result

Your patsubst never matches; your pattern has directory parts but the strings to match don't.

@molbdnilo so what I have to write instead of  $(notdir $(SRC)) ?

I think you want $(patsubst %.cpp $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o $(notdir $(SRC))), since you're only interested in the file names.

@molbdnilo now I got make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/main.o', needed by 'bin/Application'.  Stop. BTW is my SRC variable correct?

I think it's a mistake to try to build both source directories into the same directory. For instance, you can't separate the object dependencies according to source in the way you're trying to do.

Note that there are several places in your makefile where you mistakenly use SRC rather that SRC_DIR.

@G.M. I found the first one its $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.cpp'
but where are other?

The other one is in the original OBJ =  assignment -- should be OBJS = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRC))).  Although if you change that assignment as suggested by molbdnilo then that becomes moot.  You've also missed out a '/' in $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o:$(SRC_DIR)%.cpp-- should be$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o:$(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp`.

@G.M. what about IMGUI_DIR ??
this OBJS = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRC))) works only for SRC_DIR.

I solved it. please refer to the updated post

@user3473485 I know it's late, but please do not edit your original post to show the solution! Instead, leave it as it was, and post an answer yourself. Otherwise, somebody coming here wouldn't understand the problem. Your question and answer could be helpful to others with a similar problem. The site also encourages you to mark your own answer as accepted. Thank you!
